# Date time, wrong day and month

Tags: javascript

I'm using this function to get the current datetime.

The problem is that the month and day are wrong. What could I be doing wrong?

Is there also a way to give a spacing between days and hours?

E.g.: `24/10/2019 18: 50: 12: 02`

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.date = new Date().getDay() + '/' + new Date().getMonth() + '/' + new Date().getFullYear() + '' + new Date().getHours() + ':' + new Date().getMinutes() + ':'+  new Date☮.getSeconds()
}, 1);
```

Comment: ["The `getDay()` method returns **the day of the week** …"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) and ["The `getMonth()` method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, **as a zero-based value** (where zero indicates the first month of the year)"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

Comment: i recommend to use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com) to do something with datetime.

Comment: @insertusernamehere You're right, but instead of getDay, so what? Should I opt for another method?

Comment: @pbachman  
I've used it and got it, but then I'll have problems with ngmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @insertusernamehere said: `getDay` returns day of the week and `getMonth` starts on 0.

To get `24/10/2019 18: 50: 12: 02` | `DAY/MONTH/YEAR HOUR: MINUTE: SECOND: MILLISECOND` The following works

```
date = `${d.getDate()}/${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getFullYear()} ${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}:${d.getSeconds()}:${d.getMilliseconds()}`;
```

Which returned: `"24/10/2019 13:13:11:308"`